# Which Items returns the Sent Date and Recieved Date Values in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

I am using Lotus Notes Java API for my application. I have send one mail from my lotus notes account. I need to get the sent date of that mail using java API. I want to know in which item contains the **sent date** information. I have printed all the Item names and its values for that document. But I need sent date informations and also recieved date informations. Can any one help me how to get these informations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sent date is in the `PostedDate` field.

The received date is in the `DeliveredDate` field.